# i have an array and how its displayed

Tags: php, arrays

is it possible to an array displayed like this

```
$a = array(array( 'dates' => '12-11-13',
        'customer' => 'ann',
        'place' => 'EKM'),array('dates' => '12-11-13',
        'customer' => 'annex',
        'place' => 'KLM'),array('dates' => '13-11-13',
        'customer' => 'anna',
        'place' => 'PTA')
      );
```

so that the output would be:

```
dates:12-11-13
customer:ann
place:EKM
customer:annex
place:KLM

dates:13-11-13
customer:anna
place:PTA
```

Comment: Your expected output’s formatting is inconsistent. And use a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
Single Array

 <?php

  $test=array("data1","data2","data3");

  echo "I like " . $test[0] . ", " . $test[1] . " and " . $test[2] . ".";

 ?>

Multiple Array
<?php

 $test=array("teatdata"=>"testdata","testdata1"=>array("testinnderarraydata"=>"data"));
 echo $test['testdata1']['testinnderarraydata'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So to give your a more informed answer, what you need to do first is get the array properly stored so that you can iterate over it properly, it seems your key is dates so what you should do when compiling the array is save it with everything of like (dates) keys together.

Example:

```
// Array Creation
$orders = array();
$orders['12-11-13'][] = array('customer' => 'ann', 'place' => 'EKM');
$orders['12-11-13'][] = array('customer' => 'annex', 'place' => 'KLM');
$orders['10-11-13'][] = array('customer' => 'alex', 'place' => 'MCD');
$orders['10-11-13'][] = array('customer' => 'ronald', 'place' => 'BK');
```

This is just an example of a array being created with like keys.

Then you would iterate over the array to display how you want it like so

```
foreach($orders as $date => $order)
{
    echo "Date: {$date} \n";
    foreach($order as $data)
    {
        echo "Customer: " . $data['customer'] ."\n";
        echo "Place: " . $data['place'] ."\n";
    }

    echo "\n\n";
}
```

And to put it all together should give you want you need.

```
<?php 
// Array Creation
    $orders = array();
    $orders['12-11-13'][] = array('customer' => 'ann', 'place' => 'EKM');
    $orders['12-11-13'][] = array('customer' => 'annex', 'place' => 'KLM');
    $orders['10-11-13'][] = array('customer' => 'alex', 'place' => 'MCD');
    $orders['10-11-13'][] = array('customer' => 'ronald', 'place' => 'BK');


    foreach($orders as $date => $order)
    {
        echo "Date: {$date} \n";
        foreach($order as $data)
        {
            echo "Customer: " . $data['customer'] ."\n";
            echo "Place: " . $data['place'] ."\n";
        }

        echo "\n\n";
    }
?>
```

CLI Output:

```
$ php test.php 
Date: 12-11-13 
Customer: ann
Place: EKM
Customer: annex
Place: KLM


Date: 10-11-13 
Customer: alex
Place: MCD
Customer: ronald
Place: BK
```

Comment: thank you for your support..but i want   this array  in above format                                 $a = array(array( 'dates' => '12-11-13',
        'customer' => 'ann',
        'place' => 'EKM'),array('dates' => '12-11-13',
        'customer' => 'annex',
        'place' => 'KLM'),array('dates' => '13-11-13',
        'customer' => 'anna',
        'place' => 'PTA')
      );

Comment: @user3049172 to do it that way you would have to iterate over that array to make all like dates combine into one array. To get it to display how you want it.